# Is this i7 computer worth?

Tags: gaming

So.. I'm building my very first gaming setup and so far it seems like it is really good and it will get the work done. I'm here seeking for suggestions from people who actually know about this. **Will this run actual games in ultra? Maybe you can suggest me better fans to improve the default ones (quiter is better)** Also, I'm using just one SSD, I see some people use two, **why?**

Check the build on [**PCPartPicker**](http://pcpartpicker.com/list/nGGqbj) or [**Amazon**](https://amzn.com/w/24LRMI5W3GZN6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, some more information would be appreciated.

---

### Use case:

First, what kind of games do you play? Let us assume AAA titles as they tend to be the most demanding in terms of hardware.
Second, what resolution and refresh rate do you play at? For 1080p, 60Hz you will be more than fine. Arguably, for that resolution your GTX 1080 is a bit overkill; a 1070 should suffice.

For 1440p you should be able to max out all titles, possibly with a lighter form of anti-aliasing and a smaller sample count.

Anything 4k you will not need heavy AA in the first place, so with tweaking demanding effects like some lightnings and AO you will be able to maintain 60 FPS.

---

### Suggested changes:

My recommendation for your build would be to change the CLC to a good air cooler. They are bulkier indeed, but offer equal, if not better, performance at the same price point often with less noise produced. [Something like this](http://pcpartpicker.com/product/9bFPxr/be-quiet-cpu-cooler-bk019) should do the job, and do it good.
On that note, if you intend to go past a soft CPU overclock (anything over 1.28-1.3VCore) for 24/7 usage, I would recommend a motherboard with a beefier power phase design.

---

### Further information:

The number of SSDs doesn't really matter, unless you need the tremendous speed from a RAID 0 array.
On that subject, you could use the m4 socket for [the same SSD](http://pcpartpicker.com/product/8WZ2FT/samsung-internal-hard-drive-mzn5e250bw) and squeeze out some extra performance while having less clutter.

---

### Fans:

- Should you decide to stay with the AIO, I could not recommend the EK Vardars enough to put on the radiator - I run a total of 12 fans on my rads and I'm very happy with them!
- Case fans: well I use Vardars on mine, but I've heard that the Corsair SP120 fans are great.

---

P.S. Sorry but I cannot provide more than two links due to lack of Reputation. :)

Comment: This is awesome! I think I'll stay with Liquid Cooling, I'll also keep 1080 because you never know ;) I already dropped from 32gb of ram to 16gb so I don't want do to any major changes. I'm getting those Corsair SP120, as seen on the reviews, it works perfectly on my case (NZXT H440). Thanks!

Comment: Very well. Overall it's a good build! I only recommend the m2 SSD. :)  Also, the reason I suggested the air cooler is that these CLCs are generally not as reliable - I've already had two die on me, so unless you are going for a custom loop (which, admittedly, are far more expensive), there is seldom a good reason for a  CLC apart from looks. If you find it noisy, consider putting some radiator fans on it.